# Deliver 3rd party images through secure proxy, using Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, proxy, mod-proxy

I'm working on a site which shows lots of images hosted on third party CDN's. Right now, the images are not delivered over SSL. Is there a way to use mod_proxy in htaccess to do something like the following -

https://example.com/imageProxy?url=http://www.example.org/some3rdPartyHostedImage.jpg

Where I could take a given image URL and deliver it via my own server? In this way, I could have the images being served via SSL. I realize the security benefits of this is are a little dubious, but I'm trying to figure out if it is even possible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Weird your CDN doesn't provide SSL access.

Before continuing you must understand setting up a proxy on your Apache will kill most of the CDN benefits. Otherwise yes, you could make it.

I suggest you use your [proxy through a rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p), something in the lines of (examples straight from the documentation):

```
RewriteRule "/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$" "http://images.example.com/$1.$2" [P]
```

Or ([ref](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch)):

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.jpg|gif|png)$" "http://backend.example.com/$1.$2"
```

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, the images are 3rd party content. I don't control the CDN's.

Also, I understand I'd lose the benefit of the CDN's doing this, but unfortunately I don't know if I have another choice (since I need the images to be over SSL, but don't have control of the CDN's).

One thing I'm hoping is that with CloudFlare (which I use on my own site), I'll at least get caching working on my end, so I won't be constantly fetching the images from the CDN's.

Comment: So, with the above example, instead of taking simply the file name portion of the URL and swapping it out for another server/path. How would I take an entire URL and use it? Something like -

`ProxyPassMatch "^/imageProxy?url=(.*)$" "$"`

Not really sure how to write a correct match for what I need.